# ELF so file got flagged as Exploit, how to confirm if this malicious

Tags: linux, exploit, android

VirusTotal is claiming that file contains exploit: https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/31dd9c543e653c0cacfe152f735573e85b49df519c37a32ff76469d0dee6d63b/relations

How to confirm it is not just false positive? What is possible to do here?

Comment: From those results I'd guess it was seen to be dropped by malicious APKs and has been flagged as an IOC rather than the ELF file itself being necessarily malicious.

Comment: hi, thank you! I didn't quite get point about IOC, what does it mean?

Comment: Indicator of compromise.

Answer (score 1):

If the file was installed by the OS package manager you can compare the hash and package signature against that of the distribution. Given that it's been flagged as a malicious apk it is likely a bad rule, but if you don't have a trusted source to compare it against you can't really be sure it's not malicious.

Ps. it can still be a malicious library, just one that doesn't have any existing detections or known badness ... ;)